# How to add custom property in Microsoft Office 2007 Document

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, openxml-sdk

I am trying to add custom property in the Microsoft Office 2007 Document (docx) using the Open XML SDK.

Ref:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh674468(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh674468%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

The API sets the custom property but when trying to open the document from the Microsoft Office 2007 Application, it gives error message the document is corrupted" and it cannot open that document.

Are there any other API to add custom property in **Microsoft Office 2007 Document (docx)**

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the code exactly as given in the MSDN example, or your own code? If it is your own code, please provide your code (and ideally, a link to the .docx it is producing).

Comment: I used the exactly same code. It seems that the code works only for the document of Office 2010 and Office 2013. For Office 2007, I have found the solution from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87711/Manipulate-Docx-with-C-without-Microsoft-Word-inst

We have to set the property by opening the package files.
Thanks